# Unable to insert the data in room database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-room

I am facing the compile time error in `ModelView class.Debug`.

I have already tried a lot but unable to identify the root cause.

`AddDataActivity class:`

```
private void saveWord() {

        String WordTitle=title.getText().toString().trim();

        String Meaning=meaning.getText().toString().trim();

        String Example= example.getText().toString().trim();

        if (WordTitle.trim().isEmpty() || Meaning.trim().isEmpty() || Example.trim().isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "plese insert title & description", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        Calendar calforDate= Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat currentDateFoemat= new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy");
        String date=currentDateFoemat.format(calforDate.getTime());

        Calendar calForTime= Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat currentTimeformat= new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
        String time=currentTimeformat.format(calForTime.getTime());

        WordTable wordTable=new WordTable(WordTitle,Meaning,Example,date,time);
        wordViewModel.insert(wordTable);
        Toast.makeText(this,"saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

WordTable class:
...

@Entity(tableName = "word_table")
public class WordTable {

```
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private int id;

private String wordTitle;
private String wordMeaning;
private  String wordExample;
private String date;
private String time;

public WordTable(String wordTitle, String wordMeaning, String wordExample, String date, String time) {
    this.wordTitle = wordTitle;
    this.wordMeaning = wordMeaning;
    this.wordExample = wordExample;
    this.date = date;
    this.time = time;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getWordTitle() {
    return wordTitle;
}

public String getWordMeaning() {
    return wordMeaning;
}

public String getWordExample() {
    return wordExample;
}

public String getDate() {

    Calendar calforDate= Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat currentDateFoemat= new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy");
    date=currentDateFoemat.format(calforDate.getTime());
    return date;
}

public String getTime() {

    Calendar calForTime= Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat currentTimeformat= new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
    time=currentTimeformat.format(calForTime.getTime());
    return time;
}
```

}

WordRepository class:

public class WordRepository {

```
private WordTableDao wordTableDao;
private LiveData<List<WordTable>> getAllwords;

public WordRepository(Application application){

    WordDatabase wordDatabase= WordDatabase.getInstance(application);

    wordTableDao=wordDatabase.wordTableDao();
    getAllwords=wordTableDao.getAllword();

}

public void insert(WordTable wordTable)
{
    new insertAyncTask(wordTableDao).execute(wordTable);
}

public void update(WordTable wordTable)
{
    new updateAyncTask(wordTableDao).execute(wordTable);
}

public void delete(WordTable wordTable)
{
    new deleteAyncTask(wordTableDao).execute(wordTable);

}

public void deleteAllWord()
{
        new deleteAllAyncTask(wordTableDao).execute();
}

public LiveData<List<WordTable>> getGetAllwords() {

    return getAllwords;
}



public  static  class insertAyncTask extends AsyncTask<WordTable,Void,Void>{

    private WordTableDao wordTableDao;
    private insertAyncTask(WordTableDao wordTableDao)
    {
        this.wordTableDao=wordTableDao;
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(WordTable... wordTables) {
            wordTableDao.insert(wordTables[0]);

        return null;
    }
}
public  static  class updateAyncTask extends AsyncTask<WordTable,Void,Void>{

    private WordTableDao wordTableDao;
    private updateAyncTask(WordTableDao wordTableDao)
    {
        this.wordTableDao=wordTableDao;
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(WordTable... wordTables) {
        wordTableDao.update(wordTables[0]);

        return null;
    }
}
public  static  class deleteAyncTask extends AsyncTask<WordTable,Void,Void>{

    private WordTableDao wordTableDao;
    private deleteAyncTask(WordTableDao wordTableDao)
    {
        this.wordTableDao=wordTableDao;
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(WordTable... wordTables) {
        wordTableDao.delete(wordTables[0]);

        return null;
    }
}

public  static  class deleteAllAyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

    private WordTableDao wordTableDao;
    private deleteAllAyncTask(WordTableDao wordTableDao)
    {
        this.wordTableDao=wordTableDao;
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        wordTableDao.deleteAllword();

        return null;
    }
}
```

}

Vewimodel class:

public class WordViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

```
private WordRepository wordRepository;
private LiveData<List<WordTable>> Allwords;



public WordViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
     wordRepository=new WordRepository(application);
    Allwords=wordRepository.getGetAllwords();


}

public void insert(WordTable wordTable)
{
    wordRepository.insert(wordTable);

}
public void update(WordTable wordTable)
{

    wordRepository.update(wordTable);
}
public void delete(WordTable wordTable)
{
    wordRepository.delete(wordTable);

}
public void deleteAll()
{
   wordRepository.deleteAllWord();

}

public LiveData<List<WordTable>>getAllwords()
{
    return Allwords;
}
```

}

Please help me, i am a beginner in android development.

Comment: will you please share more information  your db code and your table and the insert function

Comment: I will extra code added , please check it sir.

Answer (score 1):

Well it might be because your trying to insert Duplicate @primarykey values in to the room.make sure its not the same. when you try to update the same value it will just update.